# Angular 2 refresh issue under context path

Tags: angular, routes, refresh, contextpath

I'm developing an angular 2 app. I found a lot but I didn't find the right solution for my problem.
So essentialy, if I run the app with "ng serve" all works fine, if I refresh the page (for example http://localhost:4200/home) it works fine.
The problem occurs when I build the app in a war and deploy it on wildfly with a different context path (ex. /myapp).
At this point the routing navigation works fine but if I refresh the page I receive a "Not found error".
My base href on index.html is ""

Comment: in wildfly, you should map every http call like `home/*` to `/home`. and you should set your base href to `/home`

Comment: So at present my context-root of wildfly is "myapp" and if I change the base-href to "/myapp" so angular will look for resources under "http://localhost:8080/" instead of "http://localhost:8080/myapp/"

Answer (score 0):

Solved using 
{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
in app modules